# Prevent web-service methods to be called from URL

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have one application where I have hosted my web service,
But I want to prevent any calls made to this web service from the URL.
The methods in that web service  should be accessible from the application code itself.

Comment: Why don't you just convert it to a class library instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. You could hide WSDL, or allow only requests from your domain, or use in WCF other protocol than Http. But the easiest way is to include webservice as class library

Comment: Perhaps you can add some sharedsecrets and so your web service continues to respond to url call, but you can handle and dismiss unauthorized calls.